# Boolean Algebra Question

Tags: algorithms, boolean-algebra, artificial-intelligence

my problem is ,**Please give the algorithm:** how can rewrite an arbitrary propositional formula alfa(α) into a proposional formula beta(β) so that beta does not contain disjunction(∧) and alfa is equivalent to beta ??

Comment: $\land$ is conjunction. $\lor$ is disjunction.

Comment: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~vxc/g51mcs/ch02_boolean.pdf for general boolean algebra questions.there are many others .even in wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use De-Morgan's laws:

$$\lnot (A \land B) = (\lnot A) \lor (\lnot B) \\
\lnot (A \lor B) = (\lnot A) \land (\lnot B)$$

Notice that by taking the complement on both sides they may be written like this:

$$A \land B = \lnot ((\lnot A) \lor (\lnot B)) \\
A \lor B = \lnot((\lnot A) \land (\lnot B)) $$